# Liferay multi instances and user "request change password"

Tags: liferay

I have a question about Liferay multi instance.

I configured 2 Liferay instances: `instance1.myhost.com` and `instance2.myhost.com`.
instance1 is the principal (parent) instance.

I configured both instances to disable the change password request after account creation.
In instance1 this works well.

**In instance2 this does not work** (The user must change the password after the account creation (first login))

To disable the request change password I make it:

> Control Panel > Password policy
>
> In default password policy I disable
>   the check box: *request change*

I use Liferay 6.1 CE

Answer (score 0):

Both instances are completely independent of each other - they just happen to run on the same appserver. You'll need to do this configuration for the default password policy on both instances. There is no "parent" relationship between instances - this sounds a lot like you expect some of the settings from the "parent" to transcend to the "child", which definitely doesn't happen.